# Reading individual characters from a string constant in C using sscanf

Tags: c, string, c-strings

I'm trying to read individual characters from a string constant passed into a function and put them into an array. The end result i want is an a string array that is the same string as the string constant. This is my code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < string_length; i++)
{
    sscanf(string, "%c", &array[i]);
}
```

When string is "string" all i get is a string_length sized array with every value being an s.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sscanf cannot remember your index positioning and automatically increment pointers. So, effectively, it ends up reading the first character each time you call it in the loop.

Try as below

```
sscanf(string+i, "%c", &array[i]);
```

**Additional Note:**
You can as well use strcpy or memcpy to copy the string into a character array. I hope you have a good enough reason for using sscanf for this.